# ngnix - "listen" with and without ip address

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) related problem.

I setup a server as following:

```
server {
    # default

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;
}

server {
    # domain.foo.bar

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443;

    server_name domain.foo.bar;

    # much more directives here
}
```

Now I setup another vhost as following:

```
server {
     listen 192.168.0.1:80; # another ip of course
     listen [fd9e:21a7:a92c:2323::1]:80;  # another ip of course

     server_name anotherdomain.foo.bar andanother.one;

     # and again much more directives
}
```

If I request `http://domain.foo.bar` then the server from `anotherdomain.foo.bar` is answering and I am getting a 404, of course.

All domains resolve to 192.168.1 and the IPv6 address from above...

How are the priorities? In what way is ngnix hitting the servers? Do I have to setup an IP address that the server is listening? Why is the server without an IP address ignored while the name is fitting?

```
netstat -lnp | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      14290/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14290/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14290/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14290/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      14290/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      14290/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      14290/nginx -g daem
```

Comment: What does `netstat -lnp` show? Please add the information into the question.

Comment: netstat -lnp | grep nginx, tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5519/nginx -g daemo,
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5519/nginx -g daemo,
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5519/nginx -g daemo. what information do you still need?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the information there, it is much easier to read there.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#how-nginx-decides-which-server-block-will-handle-a-request